# Java SSL and keystore password in application

Tags: java, ssl

Sorry in advance if this question has been posted before. I have look around but couldn't find an answer.

I am creating a server in Java that has a SSL socket to accept clients. I have been looking around on how to create the socket and have started to add the code to my application. After looking around the find out how to allow a self-signed certificate for testing I found that I create a keystore and add the certificate to that. To use the certificate I would need to add "System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStore", "keystorename.jks")" The only problem is I have to specify the password in the code as well if I go off other developers examples.

I would like to know if I have to specify the password and if I do need to what is the security implications?

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you do, and the security implication is that the password is (1) fixed by the code and (2) probably visible in the object code. The solution to (2) is ultimately physical security of the software and the host it runs on.

Comment: Hi,Thanks for the reply. What could someone do if the did get the password to the keystore?

Comment: @EJP, what do you mean by "ultimately physical security of the software"? OP, please do not hard-code the keystore password within your code, because you might want to change it at some point. Instead, consider reading the keystore path and password from a property file that's stored on the server. This is how most servlet containers (e.g. JBoss/WildFly) handle SSL configuration.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. @Mick Mnemonic I will definitely be storing it into file.